# Some Font Awesome icons won't show on Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, font-awesome

Some icons are not showing in Mozilla Firefox. Specifically, the SoundCloud icon. I already checked many threads about this and none of the solutions worked for me. I'm using CDNJS and AdBlock is disabled.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

Comment: if you could make a demo it would be great

Comment: Here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/pz4eyz1a/1/

Apparently it is working in Firefox on jsfiddle, but not in my Wordpress site, which is hosted locally using Wamp.

Comment: how come it works for me in firefox too

Comment: Maybe something in my site is causing this problem. I just found this console error in Firefox, in my site: `Expected 'none' or URL but found 'progid'.  Error in parsing value for 'filter'.  Declaration dropped.` on `font-awesome.min.css:4`

Answer (score 0):

Just found out the theme that I'm using on WordPress already uses Font Awesome, but an older version which did not include the SoundCloud icon and was using local font files. So I deleted these files and updated with the newest ones.